# Adding text dynamically to point popups in highcharts.js

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I've faced a problem with inclusion of text in popup window which appears in point , this is [link](http://jsfiddle.net/tGguS/1/) to example. i want to place my own text from my array named myText  at each point popup. Any suggestions?

link to [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tGguS/1/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this as the formatter function:

```
tooltip: {
    formatter: function() {
        return '<b>'+ myText[this.point.x] +'</b>';
    }
}
```

jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/tGguS/2/

Comment: One more question: how can i redirect to some page if pont is clicked?

Comment: Highcharts has an excellent documentation. This is probably what you are looking for: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series.data.events.click Good luck!